# Split row containing range into multiple rows by any number

Tags: r, plyr

Given a data.frame where start and end represents ranges.

```
id   start   end
 1       3    51
 2      20    28
```

I'm trying to split the rows into multiple rows if the range contains another number or sequence of numbers and grouping them, for example by 25

```
id   start   end  splitGroup
 1       3    25           0
 1      25    51          25
 2      20    25           0
 2      25    28          25
```

Functioning similarly to splitting by a regular sequence here using the plyr package

```
df <- data.frame(
  id    = c(1:2),
  start = c(3,20),
  end   = c(51,28)
)

splitBy <- 20

rowSplit <- function(df, splitBy){

  newDf <- ddply(df, .(id), function(x){
    data.frame(
      id = x$id,
      start = x$start,
      end = x$end,
      splitGroup = seq(
        floor(x$start/splitBy)*splitBy, 
        floor(x$end/splitBy)*splitBy, 
        by=splitBy
      )
    )
  })

  newDf <- within(newDf, {
    start <- ifelse(
      floor(start/splitBy)*splitBy == splitGroup,
      start, 
      splitGroup 
    )
    end <- ifelse( 
      end < (splitGroup + splitBy), 
      end,  
      (splitGroup + splitBy)
    )
  })  

  return(newDf)
}

rowSplit(df, splitBy)

id  start   end   splitGroup
 1      3    20            0
 1     20    40           20
 1     40    51           40
 2     20    28           20
```

How can this be done using any singel number or irregular set of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop, as suggested by @carl-whitthoft, rows can be split at *one* breaking point. But this procedure takes a very long time, so if speed is of no concern this works.

```
rowSplit <- function(df, splitAt, id ="id", start = "start", end = "end"){

  splitRow <- ifelse( df[ ,start] < splitAt & df[ ,end] > splitAt, TRUE, FALSE)

  newDf <- data.frame(
    id    = integer(), 
    start = numeric(),
    end   = numeric(),
    group = integer()
  )

  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    newDf <- rbind(
      newDf, 
      c(df[j,id], 
        df[j,start],
        ifelse(splitRow[j] == TRUE, splitAt, df[j,end]),
        ifelse(df[j,start] < splitAt, 0, splitAt)
      )
    )
    if (splitRow[j] == TRUE) {
      newDf <- rbind(newDf, c( df[j,id], splitAt, df[j,end], splitAt ))
    }
  }

  colnames(newDf) <- c("id", "start", "end", "group")

  return(newDf)
}
```

Splitting at 25:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id    = c(1:2),
  start = c(3,20),
  end   = c(51,28)
)

rowSplit(df, 25)

id start end group
 1     3  25     0
 1    25  51    25
 2    20  25     0
 2    25  28    25
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start at using a mod function:

```
 smod <- df$start%/%25   # 0 0
 emod<-df$end%/%25      # 2 1
 newstart<-numeric(0)
 matchit<-25*(1:100) # or at least extend to maximum value in your dataframe
 for (j in 1:2) { newstart<-c(newstart,df$start[j])
    if(emod[j]>0) newstart<-c(newstart, min(matchit[matchit>df$start[j]])) }

Rgames> newstart
[1]  3 25 20 25
```

Calculate `newend` in a similar manner and you should be set.

Comment: The mod function works well to get the number of bins. However the loop would create a new start when the break point is smaller than the start. Example, `df$start <- 20` and `splitBy <- 5` would give two new start numbers 20 and 25, not one, 20. This can be avoided by checking if the start is larger than the splitting number by adding `newstart[length(newstart)] < splitBy` to the `if` statement. It might be  easier, as you suggest, to do it all in a loop rather than a ddply function.

Comment: @sbebop  Good points.  I hadn't got around to checking for any of the "corner cases."